# Can't read a video file using Videocapture() on android

Tags: android, opencv, video-capture

I'm new to android and don't have much knowledge about using opencv in android. I want to read a video from storage and extract the frames but I can't read the video. I used videocapture but it is always showing failed. Here is the code snippet I'm using. The video file path is **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/demoVid/Demo.avi**. The file size is 250MB

```
        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();
//        cap.open(vpath.toString());
        cap.open(imFile);
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        int framecount = 0;

        if(cap.isOpened()){
            Log.d("VideoCapture","Videocapture successful");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("VideoCapture","Videocapture failed");
        }
```

Comment: If you share the error message you are seeing there is a better chance to get some input and feedback.

Comment: I resolved the issue. It was the issue of opencv version. I was using older version, updating it to version 4.5 solved the issue. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Great! If you want to add more detail on the error you saw to your question and then post the solution you found as an answer below then it may help others also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I just wanted to read a video file in android using videocapture of opencv. I was using opencv version 3.4.10 which was giving error of file not found. I tried to change paths and checked if the path was properly defined but still couldn't read the file. After wasting a lot of time on it I upgraded to opencv version 4.5.0 (upgraded to get sift features) and my issue was resolved for the same code. So maybe some older versions opencv don't support videocapture. Also I would like to mention that the frames I read from the videocapture take a lot of time due to which I wasn't able to get a real-time experience.