# Using opencv to extract frames and output is empty

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I am reading the video files and trying to save them in the train folder but I am unable to see any output. I am not sure what is wrong here?

The frames are not generated in the test folder or it throws any error. Could someone please tell me whats wrong?

I am using collab to run this code.

```
Inside this **test['video_name']**

0   ../content/drive/MyDrive/Second_model/data/noncrash/event_frame_80.mp4
1   ../content/drive/MyDrive/Second_model/data/noncrash/event_frame_98.mp4
2   ../content/drive/MyDrive/Second_model/data/crash/event_frame_117.mp4
3   ../content/drive/MyDrive/Second_model/data/noncrash/event_frame_65.mp4
```

## storing the frames from training videos

```
for i in tqdm(range(test.shape[0])):
    count = 0
    videoFile = test['video_name'][i]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(' '+videoFile.split(' ')[0].split('/')[6])   # capturing the video from the given path
    frameRate = cap.get(10) #frame rate
    x=1
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        frameId = cap.get(1) #current frame number
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if (ret != True):
            break
        if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
            # storing the frames in a new folder named train_1
            filename ='/content/drive/MyDrive/Second_model/test_1' + videoFile.split('/')[6].split(' ')[0] +"_frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1
            cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
    cap.release()
```

Output:

```
    100%|██████████| 4/4 [00:00<00:00, 2412.78it/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade opencv to 4.5.. I hope it will solve your problem as it worked for me too.

[Can't read a video file using Videocapture() on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433509/cant-read-a-video-file-using-videocapture-on-android/65959726#65959726)